# replace the xml element with php

Tags: php, xml

I want the peter element replace to other element I Input It.I try to use `replace()`but it not work.I don't know my code is that right or wrong.
I hope have someone to fix my problem.Thx

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>   
<information>
    <name>peter</name>
</information>
</document>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">                
            Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
             <input type="submit" name="ok" value="add" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="check" formaction="read.php" value="check the date" />              
        </form>



        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
  $xml= new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
  $xml->load("write.xml");

  $rootTag=$xml->getElementsByTagName("document")->item(0);
  $dataTag=$xml->createElement("information");  
  $NameTag= $xml->createElement("name",$_POST['name']);

  $dataTag->appendChild($NameTag); 
  $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);

  $dataTag->replaceChild($NameTag,$NameTag);


  $xml->formatOutput = true;
  $string_value=$xml->saveXML();
  $xml->save("write.xml");
        }
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you replacing a node with itself? rather pointless operation...

Comment: actually,I don't know the replaceChild() what should be input can do the replace the peter element

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution could be to find the current name element, create a new name element, and then use [replaceChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) to replace the current name element with the new name element:

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="add"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="check" formaction="read.php" value="check the date"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
    $xml = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $xml->load("write.xml");

    $currentNameElement = $xml->getElementsByTagName('information')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
    $newNameElement = $xml->createElement("name", $_POST['name']);
    $currentNameElement->parentNode->replaceChild($newNameElement, $currentNameElement);

    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $string_value = $xml->saveXML();
    $xml->save("write.xml");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wolf Nice! If this answer helped you solve your problem, you can always consider marking the answer as accepted.